# Entity Framework 6, different child properties sharing the same base foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent, tph

I have a hierarchy of classes that is TPH in database. So we have a class `Base`, and children inheriting from it. Let's say they are `ChildrenA`, `ChildrenB`, `ChildrenC`.

The `Base` classes hierarchy have a conceptual relation to another classes hierarchy (also expressed in TPH in database) where the base class is `RelatedBase`, having children class `RelatedChildrenA`, `RelatedChildrenB`, `RelatedChildrenC`.

The conceptual relation is that :

- `ChildrenA` could be related only to a `RelatedChildrenA`
- `ChildrenB` could be related only to a `RelatedChildrenB`
- `ChildrenC` could be related only to a `RelatedChildrenC`

I'm using entity framework fluent mapping with [independent association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595818/mapkey-vs-hasforeignkey-difference-fluent-api) `MapKey` method, to avoid exposing the foreign key id as a property.

So, basically, there is only one foreign key from a TPH hierarchy to another TPH hierarchy.

Given this foreign key is called RelatedId in database, I'm trying to express my fluent mapping as follow :

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<ChildrenA>().HasOptional(e => e.RelatedChildrenA)
 .WithOptionalDependent()
 .Map(a => a.MapKey("RelatedId"));

ModelBuilder.Entity<ChildrenB>().HasOptional(e => e.RelatedChildrenB)
  .WithOptionalDependent()
  .Map(a => a.MapKey("RelatedId"));

ModelBuilder.Entity<ChildrenC>().HasOptional(e => e.RelatedChildrenC)
  .WithOptionalDependent()
  .Map(a => a.MapKey("RelatedId"));
```

Unfortunately, this produce the following error :

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   RelatedId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property
>   name 'RelatedId' is already defined. RelatedId: Name: Each property
>   name in a type must be unique. Property name 'RelatedId' is already
>   defined.

Is this ever possible to map the same children property to the same base foreign key ?

Comment: Ok, looks like it is not possible.
See:    
  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744278/ef6-tph-foreign-key-mapping-in-derived-classes-using-base-class-property  
  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900155/how-to-map-foreign-keys-between-tph-tpt-objects-entity-framework-code-first